# .htaccess redirection error in Joomla site

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I have Joomla site which was working fine for a long time suddenly stopped working like it was showing only index.html page it is not redirecting to some other pages my htaccess is posted below.

```
##### RewriteEngine enabled - BEGIN
RewriteEngine On
##### RewriteEngine enabled - END

## Send ETag (selected method: )
##### Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits -- BEGIN
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} proc/self/environ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_(en|de)code\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
##### Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits -- END
##### Advanced server protection rules exceptions -- BEGIN
##### Advanced server protection rules exceptions -- END

##### Advanced server protection -- BEGIN

##### Advanced server protection -- END

##### Joomla! core SEF Section -- BEGIN
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
##### Joomla! core SEF Section -- END
```

as suggested in some sources i have given permissions as 755 and 644 for files and folders, still i have this problem in my live application any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`index.php` needs to be loaded for Joomla to operate.

If `index.html` is being loaded instead this may have more to do with your hosting configuration.

You can rename the `index.html` file if you don't want that to load or you could add a directive to your `.htaccess` file as follows:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

`index.php` will then be loaded in preference to `index.html`.